# How to get following text using Regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I have following text with me,

```
File <a class='ub link' data-menu-identifier='files' data-url-identifier='/files/detail/n0tlz'>Medical bills & LTA.xlsx</a>  was attached to the case by {updatedby} on {updatedon}
```

What I need is, I need regex that will give me 'n0tlz' from the given text. Please take note that this is not static I need to extract from this pattern.

I have achieved at some level but not getting how to get required text;

I have : '/files/detail/n0tlz' where '/files/detail/{code}'  is always there, I just want value of {code} in given sample {code} = n0tlz

```
 // Extract The filecode 
                    const string pattern = @"files\/detail\/(.*)'>";
                    // Instantiate the regular expression object.
                    var r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
                    var m = r.Match(fileUpdate.UpdateText);
```

here m has value : /files/detail/n0tlz'> 
but I just wants 'n0tlz' I feels I am too close, just one last step is requires to obtain code value.

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML/XML parser to get the attribute value and just use `Split` to get the value you need?

Comment: MUST you use regex? Because something simple as `yourstring.Split("/").Last()` would get that for you

Comment: I need to do it at serverside at this is db's column & i m working on migration task..

Answer (score 1):

```
// Extract The filecode 
                    const string pattern = @"files\/detail\/(.*)'>";
                    // Instantiate the regular expression object.
                    var r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
                    var m = r.Match(fileUpdate.UpdateText);
                    if (m.Success && m.Groups.Count == 2 )
                    {
                        m.Groups[1].Value; // This is the expected result 
                    }
```

Comment: I added some clarification, but it seems you managed to find it yourself already ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `data-url-identifier='/files/detail/n0tlz'>` always contains a '> you could use that as a delimiter. making your existing
 `files\/detail\/` into  `files\/detail\/ '>`

now to capture the specific value you can use a simple capture group
`(.*)` which will catch any character between zero and unlimited times.

Combining the 2 would lead to `files\/detail\/(.*)'>`.

**Edit**

> But this m have : /files/detail/n0tlz'> I just want 'n0tlz' can i get it?

Well, yes. Or to be even more detailed, *you already have it*!

Instead of using a `var` try defining the type itself. In this case that would be a [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Taking a look at the properties you will see that it contains a lot more then just the whole match.

> Groups will contain your value

Comment: that's right but can i get directly 'n0tlz' using regex ?

Comment: This is a regex pattern to obtain the value. Can be directly used using  [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)